# Difference between it is like Delifrance and it is Delifrance-like food store

Tags: usage, phrase-choice

Jane was bored with the food in our workplace's carteen.
She wanted me to recommend her some better places to dine out.
I told her that "ABC food store is well-known for Tempura and milk bread..."
To give her some idea what else ABC food store sells, I said, 
(1).  ABC food store is like Delifrance.

Now I am home, and I am wondering whether there are any differences in meaning in the following sentences:

(1). ABC food store is like Delifrance. 
(2). ABC food store is Delifrance-like.

Thank you.

Comment: I would use "similar to", and not use -like outside of literary or really informal usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is purely syntactical.

When you say

> ABC food store is **like Delifrance**.

you describe "*ABC food store*" (using the **preposition** "*like*") as *resembling* "Delifrance" (another store, supposedly known to your hearer).

When you say

> ABC food store is **Delifrance-like**.

you describe "*ABC food store*" as resembling "Delifrance" by combining that word with the "-*like*" to form **an adjective**.

***The meaning is the same.***

However, grammatically there are some implications.  For instance, if you want to express a very close resemblance between the two, you would use "very much" in the former case, and "very" in the latter:

> ABC food store is **very much** like Delifrance.
>   ABC food store is **very** Delifrance-like.

That is because in the first sentence you modify a preposition, and in the second you modify an adjective.